# App crashes when touching a Checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox

I seem to be having a problem with my app crashing when I click on a checkbox. Haven't had this issue before which is strange. I have another workspace where I experimented with this and it worked fine.

I have a feeling that its because the checkbox is inside a fragment instead of an activity this time. I have placed some code to help.

**SuikodenFragment.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

public class SuikodenFragment extends Fragment implements OnCheckedChangeListener{

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public  View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.suikoden_main_activity1, container, false);
    // you can use findViewById() using the above 'view'
    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.suikodenList1);

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_tick);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangedListener(this);
    return view;
}

/*
 * Preparing the list data
 */
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

    // Adding child data
    listDataHeader.add("Riou");
    listDataHeader.add("Shu");
    listDataHeader.add("Humphrey");
    listDataHeader.add("Kiba");
    listDataHeader.add("Sierra");

    // Adding child data
    List<String> Riou = new ArrayList<String>();
    Riou.add("Joins automatically at the start of the game.");

    List<String> Shu = new ArrayList<String>();
    Shu.add("Joins automatically.");

    List<String> Humphrey = new ArrayList<String>();
    Humphrey.add("Can be found in Highway Town. You must agree to help him find the missing child in the mountains.");

    List<String> Kiba = new ArrayList<String>();
    Kiba.add("After the battle with Kiba and his son, offer to spare his life and he will join.");

    List<String> Sierra = new ArrayList<String>();
    Sierra.add("Joins automatically.");

    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), Riou); // Header, Child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), Shu);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), Humphrey);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), Kiba);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), Sierra);
}


@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
    // Check which checkbox was clicked
    switch(buttonView.getId()) {
        case R.id.checkbox_tick:
            if (checked);
                // Add the tick to the box
            else
                // Remove the tick in the box
            break;
        // TODO: Veggie sandwich
    }
  }

}
```

suikode_list_group1.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" />
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkbox_tick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />
```

**EDIT!**

I have implemented what was suggest in the first answer. Sorry to ask for more help but it appears I have two errors. I have updated the code in this post with what was suggested in the first answer.

This line below is giving me 'undefined for the type CheckBox'

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangedListener(this);
```

This line below is giving me an error of 'cannot be resolved to a variable'

```
if (checked);
```

Comment: I;m really curious what `TODO: Veggie sandwich` is about haha.

Comment: hahaha! that was already in the code from the tutorial i found. I cleanup when it works fully :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a method called onClickListener for `android:onClick="onClickListener"`. You should try removing that line and implementing the check listener like so

in onCreateView

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_tick);
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

Let your class `implement OnCheckedChangeListener` and implement the method

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
     if (isChecked)
        // Add the tick to the box
        Log.d(TAG, "Tick the box");
     else
        // Remove the tick in the box
        Log.d(TAG), "Untick the box");
}
```

Where I assume you have set a Log TAG for your class, something like `private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();`

-EDIT-

Sorry missed what you were doing, from what I see it appears you may need to change

```
\\ expListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.suikodenList1);
\\ to
expListView = (ExpandableListView) view.findViewById(R.id.suikoden_list_group1);
```

Then change

```
\\ CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_tick);
\\ to
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) expListView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_tick);
```

The reason for this is because your checkbox with the id checkbox_tick is contained in suikoden_list_group1.xml not suikodenList1.xml. However, if suikodenList1.xml is really the layout you want to use for your list, you need to move your checkbox into that layout.

Comment: ...or just change the "onClickListener" in your XML to "onCheckboxClicked".

Comment: @tritop I wasn't sure if that would work, I didn't know if  that would put a click listener on the checkbox itself or the entire view. Wasn't able to test.

Comment: @zgc7009 it was originally onCheckboxClicked...but i tried some other solutions with no success...i forgot to switch it back

Comment: @zgc7009 I have tried to implement the code you suggested and have a couple of errors. Please could you take the time to have a look again, I have upadted the code in the first post and listed the errors. Sorry if its something really simple, still a beginner...thanks!

Comment: @theCreed see my edit. I accidentally mislabeled `OnCheckedChangeListener` as `OnCheckedChangedListener` and look at how I implemented the `onCheckChanged` method

Comment: @zgc7009 im getting an error on else. When i delete it, the app crashes on startup

Comment: @theCreed that is because I was being silly and missed the `;` at the end of `if (isChecked);` Check my edit.

Comment: @zgc7009 that has solved the problem with else...sorry for all the stupid questions. For some reason the app crashes on startup...im not sure what the problem could be...

Comment: @theCreed Check your LogCat, to see it in eclipse do `Window -> Show View  -> Other -> Android -> LogCat` and when you try to run your app it will post error code. Look through the error code for a line that startes with `Caused by...` and read where your error is coming from.

Comment: @zgc7009 thanks for continuing to help me. I didnt know what to look for in the log so thanks. It because of the onCreateView.

Comment: @theCreed Look for the corresponding line that matches the error. If you don't have line numbers activated, right click on the blue bar at the left side of your editor window perspective, where you actually do your coding, and click Show Line Numbers

Comment: @zgc7009 the line is 48, which is 'checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);'

Comment: @zgc7009 thanks for the edit, i will have to move things around after thinking about it. because...suikodenList1 is actually an id found in suikoden_main_activity1.xml layout. Inside this layout is the <ExpandableListView> only. Then I have suikoden_list_group1.xml which has the checkbox_tick id on the <Checkbox> tag

Comment: @zgc7009 i made your changes and sorted some things out. Still crashes on startup and it says its still line 48 which is checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this); which is under the CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) expListView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_tick);

Comment: @zgc7009 one final comment! thank you for all your help i have fixed it. I moved both of the CheckBox lines into the onCheckedChange method.

Comment: @theCreed whatever works, glad you got it :) It honestly takes a little while to understand how everything is connected in mobile development (Android is obviously no exception). Take some time while you are learning to really sit back and think about what is linked to what and how. It will really help in the long run (I really ran into the problem when I was starting to learn about custom list views). It isn't uncommon, good luck!

Comment: @zgc7009 great advice, thanks for the support! I learnt a lot from the initial question

Comment: @zgc7009 hi again zgc7009...I posted another question and no one seems to be able to help...so i thought you might. I have been using http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref to save the state of the checkbox. i have changed the code so it applies to my app. But I cant figure out what the 'setSilent' does. Its the only error that is coming up...Im not sure what to change it to or what it is for...thanks!